# Verilog bitwise XOR on 1-bit signal

Tags: verilog

What would happen if a bitwise XOR operation is done on a **1-bit** signal in Verilog.

For example:

```
input A;
wire B;
B = ^A;
```

If `A` is 1, would `B` be 1? or would it be X or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show is known as a **reduction XOR**.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 11.4.9 *Reduction operators*.  These operators are intended to be used on signals of more than 1 bit, for example if `A` were 4 bits wide.  In your case (1-bit), the behavior is not clearly defined.  What kind of hardware are you trying to describe with that code?  An XOR is used to compare 2 signals.

```
module tb;

reg A;
wire B = ^A;

initial begin
    $monitor($time, " A=%b  B=%b", A, B);
    #5 A = 0;
    #5 A = 1;
    #5 A = 0;
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule
```

This is the output I get on 2 different simulators:

```
               0 A=x  B=x
               5 A=0  B=0
              10 A=1  B=1
              15 A=0  B=0
```

However, since this behavior is not clearly defined, you should not rely upon these results.  You should avoid writing code that way.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I wanted to add an assertion to make sure that the signal "A" is never a power-of-2 signal, and so I wanted to use ^A to make sure it is not power-of-2, but then I thought what if A, as an input, is a 1-bit signal, then from your answer it looks to me that it shouldn't be a problem.